# Having difficulty with reading files in C++

Tags: c++, file, c++14, file-read

I am trying to get a program to read a .txt file, but it returns unreadable information. Any advice or help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    fstream file;
    file.open("/Users/Arrakis/Downloads/Toppings.txt");
    string toppings;
    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "File opening error!" << endl;
    }

    getline(file, toppings);
    while (file) {
        cout << toppings << endl;
        getline(file, toppings);
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The data that is returned is:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2511
\cocoatextscaling0\cocoaplatform0{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 
Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400
\viewkind0\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320
\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\
 partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 Pepperoni\
Ham\
Pineapple\
Veggies}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Toppings.txt` is a text file, and does not contain e.g. **RTF** formatted content?

Comment: Looks like your input file is in Rich Text Format (an RTF file).

Comment: I have tried changing Toppings.txt to Toppings.rtf and I still get the same output. Is there a different way to read a .rtf file?

Comment: @Wolf_dawg Changing the file extension doesn't change the content of the file. If it's an `.rtf` file you need a library capable of reading `.rtf` files like [Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/richtext.html) or perhaps [libRTF](http://librtf.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: BTW, if your file fails to open, your program displays a message, **then keeps going**.  You may want to `return` from `main` after you display the message.

Comment: You may want to change your reading loop to `while (getline(file, toppings))`.

Comment: You *must* save this as plain text. A low-tech way to do this is to copy-paste from your rich text editor into one like Visual Studio Code which will do rich text formatting in regular text files.

Answer (score 1):

Need to reformat the .txt file so that it contains no .rtf elements.